android studio gradle issue about not finding currently version
i have got this error when i update my android studioenter image description here
what should i do to fix that? i update all features and ide i do all things in yotube and here but still not working for me change version of gradle and jdk still not woring
Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.5.2', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

Try:


Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.


Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.5.2', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:


Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
Included Builds (No included builds contain this plugin)
Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.5.2')
Searched in the following repositories:


I can't be sure without seeing your settings.gradle.kts but check that it contains a block defining repositories to search for plugins, and that it contains google():
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google {
            content {
                includeGroupByRegex("com\\.android.*")
                includeGroupByRegex("com\\.google.*")
                includeGroupByRegex("androidx.*")
            }
        }
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

